# Why doesn't SET and CONVERT work for updating a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code, with the column SaleDate in a datetime format, and I am trying to update it in the table to a date datatype instead

```
UPDATE nashhousing
SET SaleDate = CONVERT(SaleDate, DATE)
```

and

```
UPDATE nashhousing
SET SaleDate = CAST(SaleDate AS DATE)
```

I've tried both cast and convert, but neither modifies the table, does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You want to ALTER the table itself, not UPDATE the data alone.

Comment: @juergen d do you mind elaborating on what the code would look like?

Comment: CAST/CONVERT works. They converts the value to DATE (i.e. they truncates time part of the value). But then this value is saved back into DATETIME column, and it is implicitly converted to the column's datatype which is DATETIME. But what is the reason? perform this type convertion in the query where this is needed. And use more specific and clear DATE() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ALTER the table structure for that:

```
ALTER TABLE nashhousing Modify column SaleDate date
```

This will try to convert the date strings into real dates. Check the data afterwards if it succeeded. If not, you need to change the strings first to the right format. The default date format that always works is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Of course if this is live data you should test that with a backup table first.